# UpdatePanel.update on timer.tick

Tags: c#, asp.net, timer, updatepanel

Yesterday I wrote simle example of updating UpdatePanel on timer.tick event. I noticed that  on timer.tick event code of my form class is running from the beginning. Why? How to avoid it?

[image: And how to avoid it???]

WebForm1.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs"          Inherits="TestApp.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="False" 
             UpdateMode="Conditional" onload="UpdatePanel1_Load">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="5000" ontick="Timer1_Tick">
                </asp:Timer>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

WebForm1.aspx.cs:

```
namespace TestApp
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        static Random rnd = new Random();

        int b = rnd.Next(100);               // always 1 value
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdatePanel1.Update();
        }

        protected void UpdatePanel1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int a = rnd.Next(100);           // changing value
            Label1.Text = a.ToString() + " - changing value<br />" + b.ToString() + " - static value";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In result: both values are changing.

Answer (score 1):

**Why:** Because the timer is enabled when the page loads. When the time you sit elapsed it will cause a postback to the server which will reload your page again, and this is why you see the debugger goes at the beginning of you form.

**How to avoid it:** Simply set `Enabled` property to false on page load, and then set it to true whenever you want the timer to start.

Documentation from MSDN "*The Tick event is raised when the number of milliseconds specified in the Interval property has elapsed either since the Web page was rendered or since the previous Tick event."*